# User Profile Service Application Issue

Tags: user-profile-service, user-profile-service-app

I have a farm that consists of 2 WFE and 2 APP servers. I have the User Profile Service running on both APP servers and User Profile Sync running on APP01. For some reason when I access the User Profile Service Application on APP01 I get a

> "Requested registry access is not allowed".

When I access from APP02 (have Central Admin on each server) I don't get the error and everything works fine. Has anyone experienced this issue? Or can anyone shed some light on where to look for debugging the issue.

Comment: I assume you have a Correlation id associated with this error. Check the log files with that ID which can provide you with more information about the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few ways you can approach this (in addition to what @AmalHashim has given you above):

You can re-run the configuration wizard on the affected machine, or just run the PowerShell command from SharePoint shell  `Initialize-SPResourceSecurity`  this will go thru and re-set local permission that SharePoint needs.

If you want to find the specific registry key, download and run sysinternals Process Monitor and then duplicate the error.  Process Monitor will show you which keys are attempting to be accessed.

Neither of these however will tell you why this happened, it could be a number of things.  Anything from the wizard not completely correctly the first time or it was changed by group policy. That will take more time for you to track down.

Comment: The logs didn't provide any additional information, but resetting the local permissions fixed my issue.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint gives a Correlation Id in the Error Page. Something like below

[image]

To find the real issue, you can copy the Correlation ID and find in the Logs files.

From the error message I believe its a permission issue with one of the Registry Key. To find which key your only option is to get more details of the error from the log files.